# Partial derivative with logarithmic differentiation

Tags: partial-derivative

So I'm trying to follow the derivation in a book on Analytic combinatorics.  We have the function $$P(z,u)=(1-z)^{-u}$$
and I need to take the partial derivative with respect to $u$,  then evaluate at $u=1$.
So,  my attempt:
$$\ln (P(z,u))=-u\ln(1-z)$$
$$\frac {P_u(z,u)}{P(z,u)}=-\ln (1-z)$$
$$P_u(z,u)=-(1-z)^{-u}\ln (1-z)$$
then evaluating at $u=1$, ending up with 
$$-(1-z)^{-1}\ln (1-z)$$

The only problem is, the author has no negative sign in his expression....did I make a mistake in the chain rule or something?

Comment: You're correct. Is it possible that the author wrote $(z-1)^{-1}\log(1-z)$ and you missed it?

Comment: Hmm, the book is at http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf and it's equation 11 on page 160, for the expected value of the stirling cycle distribution

Comment: I don't know about the maths involved, but $-(1-z)^{-1}\log(1-z)=\dfrac{1}{1-z}\log\left(\dfrac{1}{1-z}\right)$ for all $z<1$, and this is similar to what's in the book. **Edit:** If you see this comment in time, please specify that you meant page 160 of the book, which is page 176 of the PDF.

Comment: Note that $-\ln\left(1-z\right)=\ln\frac{1}{1-z}$, because the $-1$ goes to the exponent of the inside of the logarithm.

Comment: Doh, that's what I missed. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you didn't make a mistake. Your answer is correct. That's clearly a typo in the book.